# Java - stopping all tasks in ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I have a few executor services which schedule local tasks such as reading a file, connecting to db etc. These processes do huge amount of logging, which is extensive based on the fact there are many threads running concurrently, writing their own thing into the log.

Now, at some point in time an exception can be raised, which reaches the main method where all exceptions are caught. I am then shutting down all the services and cancelling each task, hoping to prevent all further messages to the log. Unfortunately, the messages are still showing up after I shut everything down... Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Here is some code

```
public class Scheduler{

private final ExecutorService service;
private final ConcurrentMap<Object, Future<V>> cache;

...

public void shutDown() {
    service.shutdownNow();
    for (Future task : cache.values())
        task.cancel(true);
}
```

Comment: Give us some code if yo don't mind. Any chance logging is done asynchronously? Are you using `shutdown` instead of `shutdownNow`? There is myriad of reasons.

Comment: The fact that you shutdown the service and cancel the tasks does not mean that those tasks stop immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The task will carry on running until it reaches a point where it detects the Thread has been interrupted. This can happen when calling some System or Thread functions and you may get an exception thrown. In your case you probably need to check yourself by calling

`Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`

It is a good idea to do this if your code runs loops and you are expecting to be stopped in this way.

Answer (score 9):

When you `shutdownNow` your executor or call `cancel(true)` (by the way `shutdownNow` already cancels the already submitted tasks so your loop is unnecessary) your tasks get interrupted.

Depending on how they react to the interruption, they might then:

- stop what they are doing immediately
- stop what they are doing after a while, because the interruption signal is not being checked regularly enough
- continue doing what they are doing because the interruption signal has been ignored

For example, if your tasks run a `while(true)` loop, you can replace it with something like:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    //your code here
}
cleanup();
//and exit
```

Another example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aBigNumber; i++) {
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { break; }
    //rest of the code for the loop
}
cleanup();
//and exit
```

Another example, if you call a method that throws InterruptedException:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(forever); //or some blocking IO or file reading...
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    cleanup();
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
    //and exit
}
```

Comment: @Bober02 in your tasks, you need to regularly check if the thread has been interrupted - when you detect an interruption, clean up if necessary and exit the task.

Comment: I don't get this tbh. I am submitting a task to the Executor service, which INTERNALLY stores all the threads. All I can do is use the API to shut this down. What threads whouls I be monitoring?

Comment: @Bober02 I have added a few examples of what your Runnables (tasks) could look like - I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 5):

Executors support 2 approaches of shutdown

**shutdown()** : Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

**shutdownNow()** : Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks.

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()

Comment: Not exactly - shutdownNow does not shutdown the tasks "forcefully", it merely interrupts them, which might or might not stop them.

Comment: Agree @assylias. Will edit my post to incorporate your comment. Thanks.

Comment: so any way for shutdown the tasks "forcefully"...?

Comment: why do you want to force shoutdown? It's not a good idea and thats the reason Java doesn't provide any direct method. (stop/suspend are deprecated)

Comment: still, the best answer I found so far. Works now as expected. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**-** Try using the `shutdowNow()` method, it will shutdown all the task started by this Executor throwing `InterruptedException`, but `IO` and `Synchronized operation` **can't be interrupted.**

**Eg:**

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool();

executor.execute();

...
...

executor.shutdownNow();
```

**-** `cancel(true)` method can be used with `submit()` method to **shutdown a particular task.**

Comment: that is incorrect - shutdownNow does not shutdown the tasks, it interrupts them, which might or not shut them down.